# Error while connecting to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to connect to MS SQL Server 2005 from java, I am getting the following error,
can anyone help me ?

```
private static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"; 
Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS); 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433","sa","root");
```

I added the following 5 jar files :

- msbase
- mssqlserver
- msutil
- sqljdbc
- sqljdbc4

The exception is :

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Error establishing socket.
 at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.createException(Unknown Source)
 at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
 at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
 at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerImplConnection.open(Unknown Source)
 at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseConnection.getNewImplConnection(Unknown Source)
 at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseConnection.open(Unknown Source)
 at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you firewall on? If so, maybe you will need to make an exception for port 1433

Comment: This thread also has some possible answers http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=419214

Answer (score 1):

Please check what protocols are enabled on the server. Go to Start/Programs/Microsoft |SQL Server 2005/Configuration Tools/SQL Server Configuration Manager. Check if tcp is enabled under SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration/Protocols for MSSQLSERVER.

Please check if you don't have named instance - SQL Server Express edition by default creates a named instance for example.

And the third - check if SQL Server has mixed mode authentication - if not it will not allow you to connect using SQL login and password. BTW it is a bad idea to use sa account to develop applications.

Comment: @Piotr Rodakam :getting error like this while enabling TCP/IP Access denied [0x80041003]

Comment: Can u tell me what exact URL To connect to MS SQL Server2005 ?

Comment: Are you sysadmin on the server box?